Can the Vigraha (Deity) of Lord Krishna or Jaggantha be worshipped even while cooking / consuming non-veg and alcohol?
Will this give any reverse/negative effects in life?

Worship means Bhakthi. When attention is not paid to the high deity it defeats the very purpose of worship.

As per Shastra, it is recommended to maintain certain rules/decorum during worship of a vigraha/deity as such vigrahas are usually set in a public location.
Worship in such public locations with dirty clothes and improper hygiene is not allowed as once allowed, multiple people would do so creating an unhygienic environment which as we all know might result in diseases, etc. Hence, such an act is considered a sin especially in an auspicious place where vighrahas are present.
It is to be noted that this etiquette is set as rule not just or this case but for most public places.
It is also to be noted that one can worship while working as long as the work is not hazardous when once complete concentration is not on it. Or in cases where one is intoxicated (drinking alchohol) as it could be potentially harmful to the person worshiping or the people around him.
The point of worship is to meditate on the Lord. Consuming non-veg or alcohol would move ones focus towards enjoying it. So, it is recommended to not worship the Lord while doing such things as it would be a complete waste of one's time doing such things while trying to worship (meditate) on the Lord.

This is not recommended as per Shastra as the rules of Deity Worship are stringent.
Here's an example reaction from the Varaha Purana for not just doing Vigraha seva (worshipping the Deity) but even offering obeisances while wearing stitched clothes.

VASTRA PRAVRITA DEHAS TU YO NARAH PRANAMET MAM, SAVITRI SA JAYATE
MURKHAH SAPTA JANMANI BHAMINI
Oh dear wife, any person who pays Me long obeisances (dandavats) with
his body covered with clothes (clothes means sewn cloth), those
foolish persons get white leprosy for the next seven births, what to
speak of worshiping My Deity with stitched clothes.”
(HARI BHAKTI VILASA 8/390 from VARAHA PURANA)

The path of Yoga / meditation on Lord Krishna or Jagannatha is open for all and free from such risks as it is Manasika (within the mind), and hence requires very minimal rules and regulations.
